# Setting subfolder as root using .htaccess and keeping link to other subdir working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set a subfolder of my website as root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine when I go to http://www.mydomain.com/ it shows the content of http://www.mydomain.com/home but I get a file not found error when I try to go to, for instance, http://www.mydomain.com/anothersub.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1 !^test/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /test/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```